# Can i use handsontable in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, handsontable

Trying to use handsontable in typescript without a definition file

```
$("#myTable").handsontable({...})
```

this causes the complier to complain "The property handsontable does not exist on value of type Jquery"

how can i declare handsontable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend JQuery in this way:

```
interface JQuery {
    handsontable(): JQuery;
}
```

Comment: I updated the jquery.d.ts file and added "options : any" and that works. could i put this in a separate definition file?

Comment: and the answer is "yes".